# undefined method `map' for #<ActionController::Parameters> Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I am upgrading my rails application from 3.2.2 to 5.1.4. 
I am gettign error on map method by using on params directly. 
Error:

> undefined method `map' for ActionController::Parameters

On following line.

```
@assignments= params[:assignments].map {|_k, value| Assignment.new(value.merge assignment_params)}
```

Any alternative to do that in rails 5.1?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can try to convert params to hash by using `to_unsafe_h`:

```
@assignments= params[:assignments].to_unsafe_h.map {|_k, value| Assignment.new(value.merge assignment_params)}
```

Alternatively, you can iterate over params with `each`:

```
@assignments=[]
params[:assignments].each{|(_k, value)| @assignments << Assignment.new(value.merge assignment_params)}
```

Comment: to_unsafe_h is working, but below method not, what is results?

Comment: @ZiaQamar I have updated my answer, there was a mistake (`results` instead of `@assignments`)