# Filtered params still can't be converted to hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, parameter-passing

I just recently upgraded to Rails 5.1.7
I have this controller:

```
def profile_setting_preview
  profile_setting_preview_params[:content].map{ |c| ap c }
  // do something else
end

private

def profile_setting_preview_params
  params.require(:profile_setting).permit(content: {
    title: [ :content, merge_tag_blocks: [] ],
    header: [ :content, merge_tag_blocks: [] ],
    blocks: [ :content, merge_tag_blocks: [] ],
    footer: [ :content, merge_tag_blocks: [] ],
  })
end
```

When I call this controller, I get the error:

```
undefined method `map' for 
#<ActionController::Parameters:0x00007f9030d2d8c8>
```

Why is this happening for filtered params? I thought I am filtering it properly and thus it should be able to be converted to hash.

Comment: Did you try https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Parameters/to_unsafe_h or `each` instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49514465/undefined-method-map-for-actioncontrollerparameters-rails-5-1

Answer (score 0):

You could change it to hash first

```
profile_params = profile_setting_preview_params.to_h
profile_params[:content].map{ |c| ap c }
```

Reference:

[Since in Rails 5, ActionController::Parameters will no longer inherit from HashWithIndifferentAccess.](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/07/25/parameters-no-longer-inherit-from-hash-with-indifferent-access-in-rails-5.html)